# Can the CanvasVirtualControl in Win2D be tweaked to invalidate smaller regions?

Tags: c#, uwp, win2d

When `CanvasVirtualControl` raises `RegionsInvalidated`, it provides a list of regions visible on screen:

```
private void OnRegionsInvalidated(CanvasVirtualControl sender, CanvasRegionsInvalidatedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var region in e.InvalidatedRegions)
    {
        using (var ds = sender.CreateDrawingSession(region))
        {
            // draw stuff for that region
        }
    }
}
```

The list of regions it returns usually has one large one and one or two small ones. I understand why it does that, but is there anyway to tell the control to use a smaller max bitmap size, such that it ends up giving me 4 medium regions?

For example, when the control first loads, it raises `RegionsInvalidated` with the following regions:

```
Rect[0] => 2000x2000 pixels
Rect[1] => 120x30 pixels
```

One large region and another small region because it knows my GPU doesn't allow bitmaps larger than 2000x2000 (for example). I was wondering if there's a way to override this and tell the control to have a maximum of 500x500, such that it returns results like:

```
Rect[0] => 500x500 pixels
Rect[1] => 500x500 pixels
Rect[2] => 500x500 pixels
Rect[3] => 500x500 pixels
Rect[4] => 120x30 pixels
```

Comment: I'm a little confused about your question, what " tell the control to use a smaller max bitmap size" mean? Did you mean you just want get only one region that is middle size returned? Did you want to just redraw one invalidate region? Why it end up giving you 4 regions? If  I misunderstand you please kindly tell me details.

Comment: Hi @SunteenWu-MSFT, I added an example in my question. I hope it's clear.